# two networks and one LAN card

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have got dedicated server from one company and the ip address which they have assigned to this server is 87.106.124.113. I have also the my ip address pool which is 80.48.94.x/24. Is it possible to use this 80.48.94.x on that server?

Could I e.g. create eth0:0 with address 80.48.94.2 and do some routing on server so it could use 80.48.94.2 for web server (so also I would be able to ping from outside to 80.48.96.2)?

---

I have run those commands, but still nothing:

```
apt-get install vlan
modprobe 8021q
ifconfig eth0.2 80.48.94.2 broadcast 80.48.94.255 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add -net 80.48.94.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth0.2
```

But I still doesn't have access from outside. What else should I do?

Comment: In reading through this question a couple more times, and reading your comments as well, I think you should involve a networking professional in this. It appears that you don't have the networking knowledge to configure this yourself.

Comment: I made some huge networks with 200 users with NAT, but I have never going deeper. I would like to get this work by myself, so even if you (@MDMarra) could let me know which articles etc is good to read for this then could be great,

Answer (score 2):

If both IP ranges are available to the one NIC via vlan trunking, then yes. If not, then no.

Comment: So I should do vlan trunking for 80.48.94.2 and then I should got access to server also by 80.48.94.2?

Comment: Hi @MDMarra, I have updated my question with commands which I run. Could you let me know what I am still missing?

Comment: Have you trunked both networks to the port that your NIC is connected to and tagged each sub-interface appropriately?

Comment: Trunk needs to be on switch? There is not any other way to do this just using server on debian?

Comment: No, you cant have two different network presented on the same switchport without configuring VLANs on the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can assign different IP with an alias. I had this setup, bought additional IP for server and those were completely different subnet, made aliases and all worked fine.